# Google markup brand logo

Tags: gmail, google-schemas

I am looking for update information regarding the possibility to implement brand logo images in email for Gmail users.

In this article: https://marketingland.com/email-marketers-need-know-getting-started-gmails-grid-view-78834, I found references to official Google documentation, but the link is not working.

This markup allows you to insert and personalize brand logo in emails sent to Gmail users, reading emails from Gmail/Inbox.

I found some articles on other specific blogs, but in the official Google documentation the markup is not more considered.

These are the external references: https://blog.returnpath.com/gmail-turns-the-inbox-into-a-visual-feast-what-marketers-need-to-know/

Do you have more and updated information?

This should be the markup:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
 <link itemprop="image" href="http://www.returnpath.com/someimage.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Anyone using it, nowadays?

Comment: You can check the [Brand Email Markup](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/types/Brand).

Comment: I checked out the reference link you've provided; it looks like the Grid View feature. Unfortunately, that feature has been deprecated. http://freshinbox.com/blog/goodbye-gmail-grid-view/